# want to access variable from function to render function in backbone

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

```
getGeoLevelDetails: function(id) {
  window.gid = id;
}
```

I want to access `window.gid` in  `renderGeoLevelDetails` function

```
renderGeoLevelDetails: function(response, obj){
  var id = this.getGeoLevelDetails.gid;
  console.log(id);
}
```

It isshowing me output as

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gid' of undefined

Comment: Why can't you directly do `var id = window.gid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your approach.

**First** you are defining a global variable assigned to the DOM window object, this inside a function which i don't really know where it's declared. But this is not really important at this phase.

**Second** you want to obtain the value assigned to the global variable by calling the above function, which does not return anything.

You have a few options here: either assign the value to the global variable (which is a very bad practice, **this should be avoided in any case**).

The better approach would be to simply return `id`:

```
getGeoLevelDetails: function(id) {
     return id;
}
```

Later you can obtain this id by calling in the `renderGeoLevelDetails` function.

```
renderGeoLevelDetails: function(response, obj) {
     var id = this.getGeoLevelDetails();
}
```

Please note this is working only if you are calling the `this.getGeoLevelDetails` function from the same scope, because `this` is an instance of the same object.

There is another big error in your code regarding this line:

```
this.getGeoLevelDetails.gid;
```

First your are **not** invoking as a function but as an instance variable, expecting to return a globally declared object. This is the reason you are getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gid' of undefined

---

**TL;DR**

To sum up, if you wish to transfer a value from a model to a view you can access this by calling the model inside the view, or if you wish to obtain a value inside the same view you can use the approach presented above.

If none of the above solutions are fitted for your needs there is another method you can approach: to extend the Backbone object, then declare an object variable which receive the desired value. This way you will eliminate the global pollution issue:

**Example:**

```
Backbone.Details = _.extend({}, Backbone.Router);   
Backbone.Details.geoLevel = id;
```

This variable: `Backbone.Details.geoLevel` then will be accessible from anywhere in your application.